# Merge 2 Lists to Remove Duplicates from the First While Keeping the Corresponding Values of the Second

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists like this:

```
1stItem version1.1
1stItem version1.2
1stItem version1.3
2ndItem version1.1
2ndItem version1.2
3rdItem version1.1
3rdItem version1.2
3rdItem version1.3
3rdItem version1.4
```

And I want to merge those 2 lists by removing the duplicates in the first while keeping the corresponding values from the 2nd so I will end up with something like this:

```
1stItem version1.1, version1.2, version1.3
2ndItem version1.1, version1.2
3rdItem version1.1,version1.2,version1.3,version1.4
```

Tried getting the index for all the duplicate items from the 1st list and then merge with their corresponding items from the 2nd list by using this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def list_duplicates(seq):
    tally = defaultdict(list)
    for i,item in enumerate(seq):
        tally[item].append(i)
    return ((key,locs) for key,locs in tally.items() 
                            if len(locs)>1)

for dup in sorted(list_duplicates(source)):
    print(dup)
```

I have the feeling that this can be solved much easier and in a pythonic way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group together the lists of items and versions based on the name of the item, and iterate over that group to create a dictionary

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

items = ['1stItem' , '1stItem' , '1stItem' , '2ndItem' , '2ndItem' , '3rdItem' , '3rdItem', '3rdItem', '3rdItem' ]
versions = ['version1.1' , 'version1.2' , 'version1.3', 'version1.1' , 'version1.2' , 'version1.1' , 'version1.2', 'version1.3', 'version1.4' ]

d = defaultdict(list)

#Iterate over a zipped list of items and versions and group on item
for model, group in groupby(zip(items,versions), key=lambda x:x[0]):

    #Iterate through the group and form the dictionary
    for key, value in group:
        d[key].append(value)

print(dict(d))
```

The output will be

```
{
'1stItem': ['version1.1', 'version1.2', 'version1.3'], 
'2ndItem': ['version1.1', 'version1.2'], 
'3rdItem': ['version1.1', 'version1.2', 'version1.3', 'version1.4']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be a little bit complicated. I would suggest to do it with Dictionary:

```
Data = [["1stItem", "version1.1"],
        ["1stItem", "version1.2"],
        ["1stItem", "version1.3"],
        ["2ndItem", "version1.1"],
        ["2ndItem", "version1.2"],
        ["3rdItem", "version1.1"],
        ["3rdItem", "version1.2"],
        ["3rdItem", "version1.3"],
        ["3rdItem", "version1.4"]]


FinalData = {}; # Create dictionary

for Item in Data:

    if not(Item[0] in FinalData.keys()): # If Key does not exist, add it
        FinalData[Item[0]] = [] # Add the key, array as defult value

    FinalData[Item[0]].append(Item[1]) # Add 'Version' to array

for Key in FinalData.keys():

    print("%s %s" % (Key, ", ".join(FinalData[Key]))) # Print the result
```

This will produce the following result:

```
2ndItem version1.1, version1.2
1stItem version1.1, version1.2, version1.3
3rdItem version1.1, version1.2, version1.3, version1.4
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary to remove the duplicate values from first list and create a list to append the values in the second list as values to the dictionary

```
first = ['1stItem', '1stItem', '1stItem', '2ndItem', '2ndItem', '3rdItem', '3rdItem', '3rdItem', '3rdItem' ]
second = ['version1.1', 'version1.2', 'version1.3', 'version1.1', 'version1.2', 'version1.1', 'version1.2', 'version1.3', 'version1.4']
#define dictionary to remove duplicates from first list
d = {i: [] for i in first}
for i in range(len(second)):
    key = first[i]
    d[key].append(second[i])
print("Output")
print(d)
```